# there is a way to know the current version of analytics API code on website?

Tags: google-analytics

there is a quick way to know if the current embedded code for analytics is API v1 or v2?

```
<script>

      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-00000000-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by API v1 or v2...but,

If you are referring to the version of the Universal Analytics JS tracking code snippet...it looks like you are using the most recent...I'm really not sure they have an "API version" associated with them.

If you are referring to the Core Reporting API...then the JS tracking code you are using has nothing to do with that. The Core Reporting API is used to create custom dashboards or reports by programmatically accessing data from your analytics property on google's servers. So, your JS snippet that gathers that data from your site wouldn't have any information on that.

That being said, if you are trying to determine the Core Reporting API version that a custom report/dashboard application utilizes...I'm pretty sure version 1 no longer exists, and people using version 2.3 or 3.0 are being encouraged to migrate their applications to version 4.0. -- You can look in the codebase for any calls to the API that look like this `//analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet` -- see where it says `v4` -- That would mean it's using API version 4.